# Using mod_rewrite with https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect all requests from `sub.domain.com` to `sub.domain.com/www`.

I've done it with this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ www/ [L]
```

This works fine when I enter the site via http but when I enter via https, for example `https://sub.domain.com`, it keeps redirecting me to http. How can I redirect https requests to https? (I tried like a 100 solutions but nothing worked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I didn't mention that the application running on the subdomain uses Nette framework because I didn't think it was relevant. But apparently Nette overrides mod_rewrite settings so the usage of https had to be configured in Nette itself.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you only want https .. you will first want to force http requests to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

then continue on with your regular redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ www/ [L]
```

Comment: I tried this but when I do it, I get a redirect loop for some reason.